# Выполнение условия, если элементы не подходят

Tags: python, if, for

```
for friend in friends_get:
    if friend == friends_list:
        print('1')

else:
    print('2')
```

Можно ли как то сделать, чтобы если никакой элемент из списка friends_get не подходит под условие, то выполнялся определенный блок? Я пытался поставить else, но тогда срабатывал и он, и условие if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

добавьте `break`

```
for friend in friends_get:
    if friend == friends_list:
        print('1')
        break

else:
    print('2')
```

Если надо чтобы `1` выводился для всех совпадений, то надо добавить дополнительную переменную

```
flag = False

for friend in friends_get:
    if friend == friends_list:
        print('1')
        flag = True

if not flag:
    print('2')
```

Answer (score 3):

Если под условием

> никакой элемент из списка friends_get

имеется ввиду вхождение `friend` в список `friends_list`, тогда так:

```
for friend in friends_get:
    if friend in friends_list:
        print('1')
    else:
        print('2')
```